# Zurb Close modal reveal window with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to close a reveal with jquery, and everything I am reading says to use this code, except, the reveal is not closing when called.

```
$("#playlistsList").change(function(e){
        var playlistId = this.value;
        var lyricsId = $('#bhajanId').text()
        $.post( "/bhajan/addtoplaylist", { 'lyrics_id':lyricsId, 'playlists_id': playlistId })
                .done(function( data ) {
                        $('#playlistsModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
                });
});
```

I managed to close the modal with the addition of this.

```
var popup = new Foundation.Reveal($('#playlistsModal'));
popup.close();
```

This closes the window, however, does not remove the dark overlay.

The overlay can be removed with

```
 $('.reveal-overlay').remove();
```

But that does not return control to the page. The page is still inactive, as though the overlay were still there. Cannot scroll or get focus.

Comment: Html content please

Comment: Loading script order also will cause issue

Comment: For that u need to remove modal-open class in body tag if present

Comment: Add tat model html code you have in question